# Calling a DLL at time intervals in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dll

Hiii all,

I am beginner in Web development and I have this task of generating a report and publish in my INTRANET site im developing using ASP.NET. I also have a DLL which is having all the functions of generating the report.I have to generate that report every one hour,get the result and publish in my site. How to do this...

the DLL's function is to copy paste some excel files into local drive read them and  generate the report.

Comment: ASP.NET/IIS is not well suited for scheduled work at intervals. Consider writing a Windows Service instead, or an executable that's scheduled by the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to use a Windows service that generates the report every hour and saves it to disk / database / or any kind of storage you like. 
If someone requests the page in your ASP.NET application, you only have to get the generated report from storage and display it.

Comment: with some google search i created a window service,added reference to my dll...called the functions inside onstart() routine..its not throwing any error or soemthing.,it is starting when i start but not giving any report..

Comment: You could face numerous problems using MS Office in server environment, for example Interop API to read excel files. Try to avoid using it, or dig deeper how to properly use Excel interop in windows service

Comment: My tasks on Excel files are "Copying from server from app domain","Reading those excel files using OLEDB and put all those excel contents into datatable which works well and good as a dll component.i tested it in a simple windows app and it worked fine..i want to do the same in service too..now im hosting the service in my machine only

Comment: Then try it in a console app, then use task scheduler to schedule it.

Comment: One more thing i want to note is in debug mode my window service code is working fine and getting me the result but the same when i build and install as a service and start the service it returns nothing..how could it be??